# php display record in colspan

Tags: php, mysql, html, record, html-table

I have a record from the database that consists of id and name and I want it output
on a colspan wherein all records are distributed in a manner 1-2-1-2-4.  My program listing that gives the http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/42/wrongb.png/ is as follows:

```
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="200">
$itemCount = 0;
$itemIndex = 0;
$colSpan = 0;  
$itemColCount = 0;
while ($itemCount < $total) { // $row = mysql_fetch_array($result)
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result)
<tr>
if ($itemIndex == 0 || $itemIndex == 2) 
{
      $colSpan=4;
      $itemColCount = 1;
      $itemIndex++;
  }
  else if ($itemIndex == 1 || $itemIndex == 3) {
      $colSpan=2;
      $itemColCount = 2;
      $itemIndex++;
  } 
  else {
      $colSpan=0;
      $itemColCount = 4;
      $itemIndex = 0;
  }
  while ($itemColCount > 0) 
  {
      if ($colSpan > 0) 
      { 
          print "<td colspan=\"$colSpan\">$itemCount".$row['name']."</td>"; // $row['itemName']

      } 
      else 
      {
          print "<td>item$itemCount".$row['name']."</td>";  // $row['itemName']
      }
      $itemCount++;
      $itemColCount--;
  }
  $itemColCount = 0;
  $colSpan = 0;
  print "\n";
 </tr>
}
</table>
```

I need help on how to achieve the desired program output.  What I need to accomplish is this one http://img828.imageshack.us/img828/4411/correctj.png.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see much difference in wrong and correct pictures. Would you be so kind and explain what exactly do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Since your table seems to have a very specific layout, I would suggest that you just drop the data into a predefined template rather than using conditional checks to dynamically determine what to print. As a side effect it becomes easier to read and work with.

You need to first save the row data temporarily into an array so that you can access all of it at once, rather than in the linear manner the mysql resultset operates. This approach will break if your result set changes in size, but so does your original solution.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$data[] = $row;
}

print 
'<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="200">
    <tr><td colspan="4">'.$data[0]['name'].'</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2">'.$data[1]['name'].'</td>
    <td colspan="2">'.$data[2]['name'].'</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="4">'.$data[3]['name'].'</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2">'.$data[4]['name'].'</td>
    <td colspan="4">'.$data[5]['name'].'</td></tr>
<tr><td>'.$data[6]['name'].'</td>
    <td>'.$data[7]['name'].'</td>
    <td>'.$data[8]['name'].'</td>
    <td>'.$data[9]['name'].'</td></tr>
```

';

It would be better to return the data in one row from the database if possible, so that you can access the columns in one row, rather than one column in 10 rows. Then you would not get into situations where you rely on conditionals to produce the html. If you are the also author of the DB end, you should consider this. If DB is not under your control, then you'll just have to deal with it as well as you can.